# Why is everything that concerns CvSeq in OpenCV is such a mess?

Tags: eclipse, opencv

So, I have a project at my job using OpenCV (and it's actually the first project I'm doing with OpenCV) and I have to use stuff like CvSeq to use the SURF algorithm. Since I started to put that in my code, it's a total mess. Apparently, it compiles, but, at least Eclipse, is considering that there's a bunch of errors. All the definitions are messed up.

So, is the problem with Eclipse, or is it that the new header files of OpenCV are just that bad, at least for that part.

Comment: This is a rather combative approach to asking a question and tends to be frowned upon.  I suggest rewriting it with a different approach - maybe along the lines of 'I am having problems using OpenCV with Eclipse and seem to be getting erroneous error reports; what am I doing wrong?'  See [How to Ask Questions the Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would highly recommend you use the new C++ interface of OpenCV. It will allow you to use `vector<KeyPoint>` objects, which is far easier to use than `CvSeq` as I'm sure you've seen. The C++ interface also has far more features than the old C interface.

[Here](https://code.ros.org/svn/opencv/trunk/opencv/samples/cpp/descriptor_extractor_matcher.cpp) is a good OpenCV sample doing descriptor matching.

Hope that is helpful.